# pskafka -- Using powershell to query brokerlist and it errors "failed to acquire metadata"

Tags: powershell, apache-kafka

I'm trying to use pskafka and get a list of topics from the broker:

```
PS H:\pskafka-master> Get-KafkaTopics -BrokerList 10.195.130.43 -Verbose -Debug
```

returns:
PS H:\pskafka-master> Get-KafkaTopics -BrokerList 10.195.130.43 -Verbose -Debug

```
VERBOSE: H:\pskafka-master\bin\win\kafkacat.exe -b 10.195.130.43 -L

> kafkacat.exe : % ERROR: Failed to acquire metadata: Local: Timed out
At H:\pskafka-master\Public\Get-KafkaTopics.ps1:26 char:22
+     [string[]]$output = & $kafka.path $kafka.args.Split(' ')
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (% ERROR: Failed...ocal: Timed out:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Any idea on why this is happening and how to possibly extend the time out?  And yes I can ping the server and do a tracert.

Comment: What does `Test-NetConnection 10.195.130.43 -Port 9092` say?

Comment: PS H:\pskafka-master> Test-NetConnection 10.195.130.43 -Port 9092


ComputerName     : 10.195.130.43
RemoteAddress    : 10.195.130.43
RemotePort       : 9092
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet0 2
SourceAddress    : 10.195.195.3
TcpTestSucceeded : True